# Whats the best way of making a web browser in Ubuntu?

Tags: helpfile

Well, I guess the the title gives it away. I'm trying to find out how to make a web browser. I don't want anything to advanced. Just a simple tutorial on making web browser witch allows you to search and view websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This YouTube video [Creating Your First Ubuntu App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO8hiPreNBg) by Jono Bacon shows how to create a simple web browser by generating a project, setting up your user interface, writing the code, and creating an Ubuntu package. *Creating Your First Ubuntu App* has been viewed more than 100,000 times on YouTube.

Comment: @keral Thanks for that, I've found this tutorial before. I've had problems following it and sadly no one could would offer to help me.

Comment: Install the latest version of youtube-dl and download the video from the terminal by running `youtube-dl -c -f 35 --title  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO8hiPreNBg`. The video has so much information in it that it is difficult to absorb it all if you watch it only one time. You can update youtube-dl to the latest version by running `sudo youtube-dl --update`.

Comment: Thanks for that, make it more clear then viewing it via web browser.

Answer (score 0):

There's most likely not a single tutorial which covers all the things you want.

1. You'll want to first look up a book (or similar tutorial) on learning your language of choice
2. Then creating a simple Gui for that language (search "gui with [language]")
3. Then creating a more advanced Gui
4. Then accessing the web through the Gui

It'll be more rewarding and you'll learn to be able to make other applications as well